# MPS: 'Make model' command does not generate text

Tags: mps

In MPS, I have a very simple model with a `System` root node.  I added a `System_TextGen` to create a python file.

When I ask for a preview of the generated text, I get to see my appended-to buffer.

```
text gen component for concept System { 
file name : <Node.name>                  
  (context, buffer, node)->void { 
    append {#!/bin/env python} ; 
  } 
}
extension : (node)->string { 
  "py"; 
}
encoding : utf-8

text layout : <no layout>
```

The text preview does show the `#!/bin/env python` line, but when I make the model, a .py is nowhere to be found.

How can I cause text to be actually generated?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special you should do to enable text generation. Try the "Rebuild project" command from the "Build" menu, in case "Make" does not find any modifications to trigger the actual make.
Also check the "generation path" of the sandbox solution, to find out where the generated file is supposed to be located.

Vaclav